# What is the process of updating record in a dimension table following SCD method

Tags: python, oracle, plsql

I want to see the historical record in scd type two form in dimension table when there is an update in the table for marketing regions considered to be updated to a new value.

I want to see the historical record in scd type two form in dimension table when there is an update in the table for marketing regions considered to be updated to a new value.our main target is to get the records updated based on the historical data preservation method.

The algorithm to update the dimension table (having less no of records-few hundreds) in SCD-2 will be:

```
FOR ALL ROWs in the SOURCE table query LOOP 
IF ( a corresponding row exists in the DIM TABLE 
THEN 
IF data are different THEN 
1. UPDATE the ""CURRENT"" row of the DIM TABLE 
SET EFFECTIVE_TO = NOW 
ACTIVE_FLAG = 0 (ZERO) 
2. INSERT new version into DIM TABLE 
SET EFFECTIVE_TO = NOW+1 day ahead 
ACTIVE_FLAG = 1 (ONE)
END IF 
ELSE 
INSERT new row into DIM TABLE 
END IF
```

so i want the new value stored as well as old value set as flag 0.

Comment: SCD type 2 is in essence an UPDATE of the current active record to make it inactive and an INSERT of the new active record. I can't really make out what your exact question is.

Comment: Actually I think that big chunk of text is you describing what you would like the code to do. Have you attempted to create this already? Have you run into issues? you should post the issue (more clearly formatted than it currently is) along with a script that you have attempted to write and the issue/error you are getting for it not working.

Comment: @ChrisCarroll- I mean i would like to see my records maintained in scd type 2 format when there is any change in source and etl process ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the block to check conditions and make SCD-2 . Also let me know what you are exactly looking for.

```
 BEGIN
      LOOP cusrsor    
       SELECT COUNT(1)
         INTO V_COUNT
         FROM DIM table_name
         WHERE <conditions here key columns and change fields here >

         IF V_COUNT = 1 THEN -- update flag and insert new record

         UPDATE stmt;
         INSERT stmt;
         ELSE -- New values to insert
         INSERT stmt;
         END IF;
   END LOOP;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have your SCD2 table, this is one way to look at it:

From a source table/tables you determine your records that came that day (incremental)/or full image records...i'll use the alias **source**

In your SCD2 you must filter the records active at the day you're loading (filter **date between valid_from and valid_to**). i'll use the alias **target**.

source
minus
target
are the records that changed/are new and need to be closed in target and reopened/opened from source.

- If you have performance issue you might want to make 2-3 staging tables that have the same structure, with a truncate / insert mechanism:

  1.One with records to be closed.

  2.One with records that are new.

  3.One with records that modified.
- If you have many tables with SCD2 you might want to make a package that generates PL/SQL ... table structure changes over time, new tables appear.

It's hard for anyone to write code for your tables, we don't know your source tables PKs, FKs(enable or disabled ?), columns.